# How to write "normal distribution", "gaussian kernel" in R

Tags: r, math, gaussian

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/brG2g.png)

thank you watching my question.

I want to write "normal distribution"(gaussian).

Don't use rnorm.

I try to write some code.
but "abline(v=mean(x)+sd(x))" was so far !
how can i do ?

my code

```
X<- rnorm(1000,50,8)

fx<-function(x,SD,M){
(1/(sqrt(2*pi)*SD))*(exp(1)**(-1*(x-M)**2/2*(SD**2)))
}

SDx1<-sd(X)
M1<-mean(X)
OO<-c(1:100)
data<-fx(OO,SDx1,M1)

plot(X,data)
abline(v=mean(X)+sd(X))
abline(v=mean(X)-sd(X))
```

abline is so far.
sd(X) is neary = 8
because, I assume 
abline(v=mean(X)+sd(X))
is (V=58).

but my "data" did n't work well.

how should I fix this ??

```
(1/(sqrt(2*pi)*SD))*(exp(1)**(-1*(x-M)**2/2*(SD**2)))
```

I want like this fig.

```
TRUE_data<-rnorm(1000,50,8)
hist(TRUE_data)]
abline(v=mean(TRUE_data)+sd(TRUE_data),col="red")
abline(v=mean(TRUE_data)-sd(TRUE_data),col="red")
```

Comment: The definition of `fx` is wrong. Try `fx<-function(x,SD,M) 1/(sqrt(2*pi)*SD)*(exp(-(x-M)^2/2/(SD^2)))`.

Comment: @nicola
thankyou comment!
but I faild....

```

###
x1<-rnorm(1000,50,8)
SD1<-mean(x1)
M1<-sd(x1)
###
fx<-function(x,SD,M) 1/(sqrt(2*pi)*SD)*(exp(-(x-M)^2/2/(SD^2)))
###
X<-seq(1,100,0.1)
data<-fx(X,SD1,M1)
plot(X,data)
###
data2<-fx(x1,SD1,M1)
plot(x1,data2)

###faild.....
###I want this
curve(dnorm(x,50,8),0,100)
abline(v=50+8)
```

Comment: It's very confusing what you wrote. Please, edit the question to insert your new attempt. BTW, you are switching the mean and the standard deviation (for instance `SD1<-mean(x1)`; guess you want `SD1<-sd(x1)`).

Comment: @nicola sorry.I am not good at english. I am sorry about make you confusing. and I solve it now! 「`fx<-function(x,SD,M) 1/(sqrt(2*pi)*SD)*(exp(-1*(x-M)^2/2/(SD^2)))`」this is my want!
I done! make density function! like dnorm!
thank you a lot !!